# How to use sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP...)?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to assign a static chunk of memory for sqlite3 to use within my process, based on the examples I've seen this should work but it doesn't, sqlite3_config() returns 1 consistently on linux and qnx.

Here's the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP, malloc(1024*1024), 1024*1024, 32);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d rc=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, rc);
}
```

rc will consistently return 1 which is SQLITE_ERROR. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_covering_index_scan.html) says:

> If ... either [SQLITE_ENABLE_MEMSYS3](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_memsys3) or [SQLITE_ENABLE_MEMSYS5](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_memsys5) are defined, then the alternative memory allocator is engaged to handle all of SQLites memory allocation needs.